# Conexão a banco de dados na amazon

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, amazon-aws

Boa tarde, eu tenho um banco de dados sqlserver hospedado na amazon, e não consigo realizar a conexão em php, tem algum jeito específico de fazer isso?

tentei a conexão dessa maneira:

```
<?php
$servername = "link do server";
$username = "usuario";
$password = "senha";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o SGBD é Microsoft SQL Server não é possível utilizar as funções da Extensão MySQL Melhorada (mysqli).

- Recomendo a utilização de PHP Data Objects (PDO) [link para a documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) dá para aceder a ambos os tipos de SGBD
- Pode usar o Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP [link para a documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php)

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar desta duas formas simplificadas

```
echo $conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "usuario", "senha", "nome db") or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error($conn));
```

ou:

```
echo $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "nome db") or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error($conn));
```

Se possuir mais dúvidas, pode tentar consultar o manual da função:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php